# Наклонить блок только снизу, и срезать грани

Tags: css, transform

В целом у меня есть блок галерея, который при скроле мне надо наклонить, нижнюю часть, без поворота, наклонится должен весь контент.
пробовал skew(), не получается, та же история и с Matrix Transform.
Кто сталкивался с такой же задачей, скажите как решили, буду признателен.

[image: Как должно быть]

Answer (score 0):

помогло свойство для родителя perspective, а для всего контента  transform: rotateX.
надеюсь будет кому то полезно